# How not prompt the user to save changes of layers that are on the edit mode?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

When a layer is on the edit mode and I click on the exit button of the QGIS project, it asks me if I want to save changes that I made (automatically). So, how can I disable it using PyQGIS? I've tried `QgsProject.instance().setDirty(False)` but it keeps asking if I want to save my changes. The image below shows the message that pops up.

[image]

How to automatically discard changes and never prompt the user to save changes?

I saw simillar questions like this one: [Is there is a signal in QGIS when a project is about to be closed?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162443/is-there-is-a-signal-in-qgis-when-a-project-is-about-to-be-closed)

But it was also an open question.

Comment: Do you modify the project after using `setDirty(False)`?

Comment: Yep, after modifying, I don't want to save my modifications.

Comment: I use the version 3.10.7

Comment: Now I updated to version to 3.14.15 and it keeps asking if I want to save changes. :/

Answer (score 5):

`QgsProject.instance().setDirty(False)` works just if you don't modify the project after using it.

If you would like it to be effective until closing QGIS, define a method including that and connect the method to `isDirtyChanged` signal.

```
def set_dirty_false():
    QgsProject.instance().setDirty(False)

QgsProject.instance().isDirtyChanged.connect(set_dirty_false)
```

Comment: I did what you said, but it is still asking if I want to save modifications. What I'm doing is: opening the project, modifying it, but when closing I don't want to save the modifications and I don't want the window asking to save my modifications to pop up.

Comment: @Samuel Did you run the script using QGIS Python Editor?

Comment: Yep, it keeps asking if I want to save the changes.

Comment: I added an image of the window that pops up. In case, I want to either disable that window, or autoselect "discard".

Comment: When I use that script,  although I make changes, QGIS doesn't ask If I want to save.

Comment: Doing same thing, but here it keeps asking if I want to save the changes made on the layes. :(

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I guess you missed "on the edit mode" part. This solution works on making changes on the project, but doesn't work if a layer is in edit mode.

Comment: @menes I've realized that later. I reviewed the source code a little, but I couldn't find a solution. Somehow we need to catch "Hey! The project is closing" event. And according to [a post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/162443/29431) in this site, it looks like it is not possible.

Comment: @menes I think he didn't miss it, it's just that the question was edited after the answer, changing the base scenario.

Comment: Sorry for not saying that "edit mode" part right from the beginning of this question.