# Displaying an alert before closing QGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3

I would like to display a message before QGIS close. But I can't intercept the closeEvent of the main window from my plugin. I've tested this code which doesn't work.

```
# Main method
QgsApplication.instance().closeEvent = self.mainWindowCloseEvent

def mainWindowCloseEvent(self, event) :
    # displaying message...
    event.ignore()
```

Comment: The `QgsApplication` class inherits from `QApplication` which has the signal `aboutToQuit()`. Perhaps you can make that work for you?

Comment: As @BenW suggested, using [`aboutToQuit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) might do the trick, maybe with something like: `QgsApplication.instance().aboutToQuit.connect(mainWindowCloseEvent)`, similar to how you connect qt signals to function in the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. It doesn't work, i can't cancel the event or display a message. The documentation says " Note that no user interaction is possible in this state."

Comment: I needed something like that before, but I couldn't find any solution. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162443/is-there-is-a-signal-in-qgis-when-a-project-is-about-to-be-closed